# Output of function will not change

Tags: scheme

I have asked an earlier question regarding how to set-up my function based on the requirements in the problem, and using already the code I had written, the problem now is that, no matter what, the output stays the same, no matter how much I change the value of the parameter `k` in `first-value-k-or-higher x tol 1`.

Here is my code based on the feedback in my other question:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x)) 

(define (first-value-k-or-higher x tol k)
  (if (<= (abs(- x
             (square (babylonian x k))))
          tol)
      k
      (first-value-k-or-higher x tol (+ k 1))))

(define (terms-needed x tol)
  (first-value-k-or-higher x tol 1))
```

Here is a couple example outputs if the function looks like the one I have above:

```
> (terms-needed 15 .001)
1
> (terms-needed 234 3)
1
> (terms-needed 23421 453)
1
>
```

If I change the function `terms-needed x tol` to something like this:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x)) 

(define (first-value-k-or-higher x tol k)
  (if (<= (abs(- x
             (square (babylonian x k))))
          tol)
      k
      (first-value-k-or-higher x tol (+ k 1))))

(define (terms-needed x tol)
  (first-value-k-or-higher x tol 100))
```

The new function will output:

```
> (terms-needed 15 .0001)
100
> (terms-needed 243 3)
100
>
```

`Terms-needed` is supposed to evaluate to the number of terms in the infinite sum needed to be within `tol`, that is, the smallest  `k` such that the difference between `x` and `(square (babylonian x k))` is less than `tol`. As I have mentioned the problem is I keep getting the same output of "1" no matter what I put down for the values of the parameters of `terms-needed x tol`. I also believe that is where the problem is coming from, because if I change `(first-value-k-or-higher x tol 1))` to something like `(first-value-k-or-higher x tol 2))` or any other value `(first-value-k-or-higher x tol 2))` will output that value, for example with `(first-value-k-or-higher x tol 2))` will output 2.

Here is the function `babylonian x k` that is needed to run the program `first-value-k-or-higher x tol k` which is needed to run `terms-needed x tol`:

```
(define (babylonian x k)
    (if (>= x 1)
      (if (= k 0)
          (/ x 2)
          (* (/ 1 2) (+ (expt x (/ 1 2)) (/ x (expt x (/ 1 2))))))
      1)
  )
```

The `babylonian` function is supposed to compute roots using the babylonian method and evaluates to the k^th approximation (Sk). The `babylonian` function passes all the tests as well.

Here is [my earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340562/writing-a-function-that-finds-the-smallest-k-such-that-the-difference-between-x) for more background information

Comment: Could you please simply state what code do you call, what it produces, and what you expected it to produce (see [mcve]). Please do not use lots of "it" and "that", because it's unclear what they all refer to. It's better to have repetitions in the text, with shorter sentences, so that the text's meaning is clear. Clarity must come above the literary style. :) As the famous saying goes, "the matters of elegance should be left to the tailor and to the cobbler". Cheers.

Comment: Yes. sorry I was going to but I forgot after I posted

Comment: Looks like it succeeds on the very first iteration. And returns the initial value of `k`, whatever that is. To see why is succeeds immediately, the definition of `babylonian` must be checked. -- "babylonian: unbound identifier in module in: babylonian" -- [mcve]

Comment: I added the babylonian function to add all parts that are needed for this question @WillNess

Comment: is this "k-th approximation" supposed to be the sum of the first k terms in the series, or is it the k-th term in the series? also, when you find the correct definition for `babylonian`, please ask *new question* with it. this one is already answered. changing it will invalidate the answer, and it's not supposed to happen on SO.

Comment: re-reading your original post, if `babylonian` is k-th term in the series, then the whole setup is wrong; and if it's the sum of k terms, then the whole setup is silly. but let's first of all find the correct definition of `babylonian`.

Comment: I was able to fix babylonian and now the whole function works @WillNess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,

```
(define (babylonian x k)
    (if (>= x 1)
      (if (= k 0)
          (/ x 2)
          (* (/ 1 2) (+ (expt x (/ 1 2)) (/ x (expt x (/ 1 2))))))
      1)
  )
```

could not possibly be computing "the k^th approximation" of `x`, because there's no `k` in the alternative of the inner `if` expression.